# Redirect loop wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have alredy tried with these three options:

- clear the cache
- delete the .htaccess file, and create a new one
- rename the plugin folder.

but still wih I press login, it redirect again to login page:

https://www.test.ch/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.ch%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

also tried to add this in wp-config:

```
<?php
define('WP_HOME','https://www.test.ch'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.test.ch');
```

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by a Plugin, I removed it thorough phpmyadmin, then was able to login